# Trying to extract a PNG from a WMS service using gdal_translate

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate

I'm trying to run the following command

```
gdal_translate -of PNG -projwin_srs "-200357 200375 200375 -200305" -outsize 512 512 frmt_wms_openstreetmap_tms.xml openstreetmap.png
```

The frmt_wms_openstreatmap.xml is located in github at https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/frmts/wms/frmt_wms_openstreetmap_tms.xml

The problem is that the negative coordinates are being interpreted as options.

I'm just trying to generate a single PNG for a portion of a world map.

Comment: You don't want to use `-projwin_srs` with those parameters. You mean just `-projwin`.

Comment: Youre correct, I just noticed that.  Was coming here to delete question.